# How to create an app and save local data using dart and flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner programmer on the dart and flutter. I want to create an app to manage my small shop and save data on a physical device. I searched for any code samples, but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas or suggestions from Flutter professionals to begin my project will be really helpful.

Comment: You can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save data locally

Comment: thank you , i will try

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [sharedPrefernce](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin for storing data. But data may be persisted to disk asynchronously, and there is no guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning, so this plugin must not be used for storing critical data.

Another option is [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)  fast key-value database written in pure Dart.
you can also explore other options like [sqllite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [firebase_database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database)

Answer (score -1):

flutter create appname - This can be used to create flutter app